# How to fix IE ClearType + jQuery opacity problem in this script?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-animate, opacity

I'm having a rather common problem (or so it seems, after some googling around...) with IE messing both bold text AND transparent pngs while animating opacity using jQuery.

You can view the sample here: http://dev.gentlecode.net/dotme/index-sample.html (only occurs in IE, obviously)

I've seen some blog posts saying the fix is to remove the filter attribute but I'm not sure how to apply it to the script I'm using since I got it from a tutorial and am still learning jQuery...

The script goes as follows:

```
$('ul.nav').each(function() {
    var $links = $(this).find('a'),
        panelIds = $links.map(function() { return this.hash; }).get().join(","),
        $panels = $(panelIds),
        $panelWrapper = $panels.filter(':first').parent(),
        delay = 500;

    $panels.hide();

    $links.click(function() {
        var $link = $(this),
            link = (this);

        if ($link.is('.current')) {
            return;
        }

        $links.removeClass('current');
        $link.addClass('current');

        $panels.animate({ opacity : 0 }, delay);
        $panelWrapper.animate({
            height: 0
        }, delay, function() {
            var height = $panels.hide().filter(link.hash).show().css('opacity', 1).outerHeight();

            $panelWrapper.animate({
                height: height
            }, delay);
        }); 

        return false;
    });

    var showtab = window.location.hash ? '[hash=' + window.location.hash + ']' : ':first';

    $links.filter(showtab).click();

});
```

I would appreciate if someone could go over it and show me how to fix the opacity issue. Will the filter method also fix the trouble I'm having with transparent pngs having pixelated ugly borders like the bold type as well?

Thanks in advance for all help!

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in like this:

Change this line/statement:

```
var height = $panels.hide().filter(link.hash).show().css('opacity', 1).outerHeight();
```

To this:

```
var filtered = $panels.hide().filter(link.hash).show().css('opacity', 1);
if ($.browser.msie)
  filtered.each(function() { this.style.removeAttribute('filter'); });
var height = filtered.outerHeight();
```

Normally I don't condone `$.browser` use, but in this case it is an IE bug and jQuery is applying filter because it's IE as well.  This will loop through the elements and remove the filtered set and take off the `filter` style attribute if you're in IE.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't do the trick. Bold text and transparent images are still being rendered very poorly (http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/3871932/iebold.png) - is it possible that it's some other bug and not the ClearType issue?

Comment: @Justine - Sorry! I must have been *really* tired answering this :) You need to set the opacity **then** remove the filter attribute, I updated the answer showing this, try the updated code above.

Answer (score 0):

I've run the sample page on (Vista) IE8, IE8 compatability, Google Chrome 4.1 and Firefox 3.5.9 - if you like I can also do XP and Win 7  - but so far they all appear to work in a similar fashion.

The problem could be with IE6 (I guess) because there are known problems with IE6 and transparent pngs in IE6, google with:

> ie6 transparent png fix

for a bunch of fixes including (which is the second in the above search in Google and the first one in the search says it is a better solution than his):

http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6

As to the jquery sample you've posted, if it still fails with IE6/png workarounds then post the html you are using with the jquery so it can be debugged.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm looking for. There is a known issue with animating opacity in all versions of IE that make bold text almost unreadable.

Comment: In the font in the example the 's', 'a' and 'v' do have some bold  jaggies in IE - those letters do render more poorly than in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem during animation, not just afterward, by applying a `background-color:#fff` style to the container in your css (or to the element if it is the container).

I got this tip from [The Strange Zen of Javascript – IE bold text + opacity problem](http://jszen.blogspot.com/2005/04/ie-bold-text-opacity-problem.html).

This fixed my IE7 problem beautifully. Also, even without using the background color, you can fix the problem after animation without messing with the filter by simply removing the opacity css property once the item is fully visible, ala `element.css({opacity: ''});`.