# jQuery expanded list items displaying slightly different in IE7

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm pretty new at this and I came across something strange that I can't figure out.  I've replicated it on my test page here.  http://www.slappotown.com.  In IE7, or IE8 in compatibility/IE7 standards mode, when you expand the first menu, the expanded menu items look slightly different from the other menu items (the regular menu items look more bold vs the expanded ones) and I can't quite figure out what's causing it.  It's very subtle but the different is definitely there.

Messing around with the rendered code I feel like it has something to do with the inline display:none on those expanded elements.  If I edit that with IE8 dev tools to display:list-item then the fonts match. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Brian

Comment: Looks the same to me. IE9 in ie7/ie7 mode.

Comment: @mrtsherman - It's a really weird one.  I can't reproduce in IE9 in IE7/IE7 mode.  It only seems to do it in actual IE7 and IE8 in IE/7 or IE8 compatibility mode.  Makes no sense to me since I thought those modes use the IE7 rendering engine but maybe there are slight differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick trip to the F12 developer tools on IE8 tells me it's the blank filter that is being applied to the li's. I suspect it could be related to IE's clear type, it's notorious for futzing with your text when animating. Maybe Nicks answer from [2678768](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678768/how-to-fix-ie-cleartype-jquery-opacity-problem-in-this-script) might help? Try stripping the filter once the show animation is complete

```
$('#menuManage a.SeeMore').click(function(){
  $('#menuManage li.hide').show('fast', function() {
      // Animation complete for one element. this refers to the current element
      if ($.browser.msie)  this.style.removeAttribute('filter');
  });
  $('#menuManage a.SeeMore').hide('fast');
  return false;
```

jsfiddle [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/fS3hJ/4/). Interestingly enough, I couldn't replicate it using jsfiddle. Gotta love ie :-)

Comment: I think that did it (original source updated).  How the heck did you see/know that was the problem?  I'm still pretty new at this and admittedly I don't even know what that attribute does.  I need to read up.  Thanks a lot for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: No probls at all. Looks like you have indeed fixed it. See the problem: I randomly turned stuff on and off in the F12 window till I found the offending bit of css :-) Know the problem: Any kind of animation with text will bite you one day in older IE's, it's just something I've learnt after being kicked in the goolies by IE a few times :)